# Why does get-psDrive not return the currentLocation for some drives?

Tags: powershell, filesystems, pwd

I have two drives on the computer I am currently working: `c:` and `d:`. When I switch between these `cd c:`, `cd d:`, PowerShell remembers the location of the last path I was in the respective drive. I *believe* this path should be accessible by the value of `currentLocation` of the object returned by `get-psDrive`. However, it turns out, `currentLocation` is empty for the `d:` drive (although the path *is* remembered) when I `cd` into `d:` again:

```
PS C:\> cd C:\Users\Rene\
PS C:\Users\Rene> d:
PS D:\> cd .\bla\
PS D:\bla> get-psDrive -psProvider fileSystem  | select-object name, currentLocation

Name CurrentLocation
---- ---------------
C    Users\Rene
D
```

I assume that this discrepancy is because the `d:` drive is an external USB drive. If this is the case, I'd like to know if this is by design and how I can get the current path for the `d:` drive.

Comment: Which Windows version are you on? I cannot duplicate your problem. The `CurrentLocation` property is only blank when the location is the root.

Comment: `[environment]::osVersion.VersionString` returns `Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.17763.0`.

Comment: You are on Windows 10 version 1809, so there is no reason that this wouldn't work correctly, unless system corruption. Try doing [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: `Get-Location | Select -expand Path` would be a workaround. however, I can also not duplicate your Problem with `CurrentLocation`

Comment: I also could not replicate the behavior